# How to say that I can hear better now?

Tags: vocabulary

When I attend a web conference, sometimes I'm too lazy to plug in a headphone. Because of this, I usually find that it is difficult to hear what people on the other side say, and so this problem put me into an awkward situation that forces me to eventually plugin my headphone.

My question is '**what should I say in order to inform people on the other side that I can hear better now when I finish plugging the headphone.**' I want to say something similar to 'I can hear clearly now'. But after checking it with the dictionary, 'clearly' is used for a writer (write clearly) or speaker (speak clearly) rather than a reader or listener.

Comment: You can say "I can hear you now" because it doesn't matter whether you could partly hear, or not hear at all, before plugging in. The focus is on what the other person is saying.

Comment: You can also say "I can hear clearly" or "I can hear better". Both are idiomatic. But as @WeatherVane says, "I can hear you now" is quite sufficient.

Comment: Note to myself. "hear clearly" is a valid phrase. I've found an example "you might not be able to hear every word clearly" on this website: https://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/course/go-the-distance/unit-3/session-3/activity-1